# Размер картинки в rem, css

Tags: css3, html5

Проблема. Логотип сайта в ширину 334 пикселя. При нормальных условиях эт должно быть 20.875rem. На мобильном экране 20.875 рем смотряться отлично, но на компьютере эти же 20.875 рем не соответствуют 334 пикселям и картинка получается меньше. Для того что б она была 334 пикселя приходится указывать размер около 36 рем. Размер указывается через css.
Где туплю?

Comment: Почему бы не указать эти самые пиксели вместо rem?

Comment: У меня разрешение монитора 1378 на 980, вроде. У кого-то может быть full hd и тогда картинка будет очень маленькой. А так пропорционально масштабируется она.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен. У меня в строке было 3 дива и в одном из них лого. Средний стоял width:100% для заполнения пустого пространства. Изменил на flex: 1 и все так как надо.